# React-Native-Webrtc duplicate images stream

Tags: android, react-native, webrtc

I'm tring to use https://github.com/react-native-webrtc/react-native-webrtc in my project. I started by using the example in the documentation and the result is that the front cam "appear" but is seems the image is [duplicated multiples times.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGmjP.jpg)

The code is pretty much the same as the doc except somme modifications to show the RTCView:

```
  let isFront = true;
  useEffect(() => {
    const configuration = {iceServers: [{url: 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302'}]};
    const pc = new RTCPeerConnection(configuration);

    mediaDevices.enumerateDevices().then((sourceInfos) => {
      let videoSourceId;
      console.log(sourceInfos);
      for (let i = 0; i < sourceInfos.length; i++) {
        const sourceInfo = sourceInfos[i];
        if (
          sourceInfo.kind == 'videoinput' &&
          sourceInfo.facing == (isFront ? 'front' : 'environment')
        ) {
          videoSourceId = sourceInfo.deviceId;
        }
      }
      mediaDevices
        .getUserMedia({
          audio: true,
          video: {
            mandatory: {
              minWidth: 500, // Provide your own width, height and frame rate here
              minHeight: 300,
            },
          },
        })
        .then((stream) => {
          setStream(stream);
          console.log('set stream');
          // Got stream!
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log('error', error);
          // Log error
        });
    });

    pc.createOffer().then((desc) => {
      pc.setLocalDescription(desc).then(() => {
        // Send pc.localDescription to peer
      });
    });

    pc.onicecandidate = function (event) {
      // send event.candidate to peer
    };
  }, [isFront]); 

  const styles = {
    wrapper: {
      flex: 1,
      justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    },
    buttonWrapper: {
      width: '100%',
      height: '20%',
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center',
    },
  } as React.CSSProperties;

  return (
    <View style={styles.wrapper}>
      <View style={{width: '100%', height: '70%', backgroundColor: 'red'}}>
        {stream != null ? (
          <RTCView
            style={{flex: 1, height: 150, margin: 10}}
            streamURL={stream.toURL()}
          />
        ) : (
          <Text>No RTC</Text>
        )}
      </View>
      <View style={styles.buttonWrapper}>
        <NitaButton
          title="Contact Help"
          onPress={() => navigation.navigate('WaitingRoom')}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
```

I can't seem to find similar problem online. Am I missing something? Thanks!

I'm using a huawei P30 pro, react-native: 0.62.2 and react-native-webrtc: 1.75.3

**Edit**

Similar problem running with the emulator.

[image]

**Edit**

I fixed it by changing video: true

Comment: Can you once try it with some other phone or with any emulator ?

Comment: I added a screen shot in my edit but it still not working with an emulator. I will try today with a P20 pro.